# Code to transfer streaming data to S3 via Kinesis firehose keeps producing the error: (UnknownOperationException) when calling the PutRecord operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tweepy, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

The idea is to stream tweets, using tweepy. My code, hosted on an EC2 instance, manages to stream tweets but nothing shows up on Kinesis (I think the error above is to blame).

I've given IAM permission (AmazonKinesisFullAccess) to my EC2 instance, so I think this shouldn't be a problem. I've made sure to use the right keys everywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different services under AWS kinesis umbrella. Kinesis data stream(KDS) and Kinesis data firehose(KDF) are different services. In the title you mentioned you are using kinesis firehose, but permissions are given for KDS (AmazonKinesisFullAccess)
Also the APIs for KDS and KDF are different as well. So make sure you are using APIs for correct service
KDF - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html
KDS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html